# MyISAM database but all civicrm_ tables are INNODB... is this a problem?

Tags: mysql, mysql-archive-format, db-logging

I just upgraded a large site to 4.7 (without any issues in the upgrade process by the way). The new "System Status" admin screen gives a warning as follows:

> "Your database is configured to use the MyISAM database engine.
>   CiviCRM requires InnoDB. You will need to convert any MyISAM tables in
>   your database to InnoDB. Using MyISAM tables will result in data
>   integrity issues."
>
> [image: MyISAM]

This is news to me. I took the database over from another person and have upgraded it a number of times already. I looked at the database and it does have some strangeness. For the most part, each `civicrm_` table is listed as INNODB, all the `log_` tables show up as ARCHIVE, and at the bottom the global setting seems to be MYISAM. The one exception is the `civicrm_system_log` table, which is listed as MYISAM.

Is this going to cause problems, and is there an easy way to get everything on track?

[image: PhpMyAdmin]

...

[image: PhpMyAdmin 2]

Comment: I had the issue also in Wordpress/Civi and changed to InnoDB with no issues to date using phpAdmin!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I backed the database up, opened it up in Sequel Pro and went to the `civicrm_system_log` table. Under "Table Info" I could select "InnoDB" from the dropdown. Then I cleared the caches on the CiviCRM installation and the system status came back green ("System Status: OK").

[image: Sequel Pro]

Per [a comment from George Lozier on another thread](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9257/myisam-database-engine-error), the MySQL query to do the same is:

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_system_log ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: This solution worked on 2 Bluehost shared hosting Joomla sites for me. No cache clearing was necessary. Thank you.

Comment: For me it was not the log table but one called `civicrm_task_action_temp...`. But changing the table type worked.

Comment: I'm a site from 4.1.0 and do not see the system_log or task_action_temp tables. What else can I try?

Comment: @Christia Take a look at any temporary tables (see: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26969/temporary-table-keeps-showing-up-and-throwing-myisam-error-and-missing-log-table/27065#27065 ) -- or just go through tables one by one until you find the culprit(s).

Comment: Catorghans answer worked for me. Thanks though!

Comment: I used this SQL query to find which table,  SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE ENGINE = 'MyISAM';   Then I was able it to InnoDB  Then I ran Catoghans reset /civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1

Answer (score 7):

Sounds good. To be sure, please execute ///civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1 which fixes the trigger and function definitions in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Single command to update all tables is:

SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ' engine=InnoDB;') 
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE ENGINE = 'MyISAM';

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue which kept recurring - traced it to an extension that I use for exporting to excel - was creating the temp file in MyISAM - removed the extension and the issue went away.