# MyISAM Database Engine Error

Tags: database, mysql

I'm getting the MyISAM Database Engine error:

> Your database is configured to use the MyISAM database engine. CiviCRM requires InnoDB. You will need to convert any MyISAM tables in your database to InnoDB. Using MyISAM tables will result in data integrity issues.

However I'm using [CiviCRM Hosting](https://civihosting.com/) so I'm sure the MySQL database is configured correctly.

When I list my database using phpMyAdmin (see image) I see three tables that are MyISAM.  These are a log and two temporary tables.  Is this a problem?  Should I try to fix this?  Should I delete these tables?

[image: phpMyAdmin Table Listing]

Comment: See also: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9177/myisam-database-but-all-civicrm-tables-are-innodb-is-this-a-problem?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I use phpMyAdmin and the SQL command "ALTER TABLE civicrm_system_log ENGINE=InnoDB;".  I also deleted the temporary tables.  This fixed the problem.